# Http php proxy server

Tags: php, url

how to recover a a url along with the message which it sends  form a client system in the proxy server.there is any command to recover the url and take the message out of the url in the proxy server before forwarding the url to Internet.

For Example:

```
http://companion_proxy/ocl.cgi?req=cnc_cmd;target=12;action=setchannel;channel=34
```

this is the url is typed in address bar,then how to recover the above url and the message such as

```
target=12,action=setchannel,channel=34,req=cnc_cmd from the url.
```

I have to extract the information from url in proxy server before the proxy server is forwarding the url to internet.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The $_SERVER variable holds the information you need:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Specifically:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

and

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

and

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
echo str_replace("/ocl.cgi?req=cnc_cmd;", "", $uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for Below code you can debug and find what you want...

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
echo "</pre>";
```